# Resource fails to load when trying to add webpart after successful build

Tags: spfx

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "348ddc24-873a-4c72-add6-aabdb4b03432" (CrudWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/react/dist/react.js' for resource 'react' in component '348ddc24-873a-4c72-add6-aabdb4b03432' (CrudWebPart). The file was not found in the server. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.
```

https://github.com/sharemypain/simple-crud

ran:

```
npm i
npm i -g gulp
gulp
gulp serve
```

but I get the same error every time. These error logs are not very helpful and I've been stuck here for a while. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: did you run `gulp serve`?

Comment: Yes, I get the error after I try to add the webpart.

Comment: to what page are you adding your webpart?

Comment: Using on-prem workbench or online?

Comment: I use the workbench on my localhost. Did you try running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your webPart to load by downgrading the react version to 16.8.5.

change the dependencies section in your package.json to the below, then re-run `npm install`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-http": "^1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.10.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "antd": "^3.22.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  }
```

Once the webpart was loading, I found a few other runtime errors that I solved as follows:

you will want to change line 14 of Crud.tsx to
`<Todolist spHttpClient={this.props.spHttpClient}></Todolist>`

And modified the `getToDosAsync` at the bottom of Todolist.tsx:

```
getToDosAsync = (): Promise<any> => {
    let response = {};
    let promise = this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ToDo')/items`,
    response = SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then(async(response)=>{ 
        debugger;
        return response.json();
    });
    return promise;

}
```